# How to scroll faster in ag-grid table using selenium/katalon?

Tags: java, selenium, awt, katalon-studio

I am using Katalon studio to run automation test cases for our application.
In one of the scenario I have to get text from certain rows in an ag-grid table.
The data appears in the dom only after scrolling.
**Here is my code -**

```
private static void verifyMetricFilter(String new_xpath, double limit) {
    TestObject dynamicObject = new TestObject('dynamicObject').addProperty('xpath', com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType.EQUALS,
            new_xpath, true)

    Robot robot = new Robot()

    WebUI.mouseOver(dynamicObject)

    robot.mouseWheel(50)

    String metric_displayed = WebUI.getText(dynamicObject).replaceAll('%', '').replaceAll('\\$', '')

    KeywordUtil.logInfo(' Metric Displayed : ' + metric_displayed)

    double double_metric = Double.parseDouble(metric_displayed.replaceAll(',', ''))

    if (double_metric > limit) {
        assert true
    } else {
        assert false
    }
}
```

**And here is the ag-grid table-**
[image: Ag-grid table]

The verification takes too long as does step by step scrolling.
Please suggest me some ways to increase the scrolling speed so that verification is faster.

Edited to add -
I tried javascript executor with this code - WebUI.executeJavaScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)", null)

But it also takes long time to scroll... I just need some method to scroll bit faster and load dom elements so that my code can fetch the text and verify.

Comment: Could you try increase the number in the expression  `robot.mouseWheel(number)`?

Comment: @donquih0te I tried increasing but still it takes long time. Please let me know if there is any other scrolling events which can be used.

Comment: I tried javascript executor with this code - WebUI.executeJavaScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)", null)    But it also takes long time to scroll... I just need some method to scroll bit faster and load dom elements so that my code can fetch the text and verify.